# Problem with KDE's pseudo-tiling side-by-side feature

Tags: kubuntu, window-manager, window, tiling

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 LTS with KDE 4.8.2. I'm having a problem with the pseudo-tiling feature where dragging a window into the side of the screen makes it occupy that half of the screen. If I've already dragged a window to one side and I decide to drag it to the other side, it only goes further into the same side, with half the window disappearing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A screencast of this might help. You might try gtk-recordmydesktop.

Comment: OP has not signed on in 4+ years and never responded to comment 5+ years ago about this 12.04 question about EOL version. As such VTC as `not reproducible`.